# Debug client side es6 application

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am using webpack on an angularjs es6 application,
every time there is an error I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Is there anything that I can use to get more specific error messages ?

Comment: Could you be more specific? 'every time something goes wrong' ?